# Applying Transform for Group resets rotation

Tags: geometry

I have 3 items. They are grouped under "Group001".

I want to rotate the group so that the object appears aligned with the axes.

To do that, I edit the rotation of "Group001".
Then I want to make it so that the current rotation appears as 0, 0, 0.

To do that, I click "Object" -> "Apply" -> "All Transforms".

This however doesn't work as expected: It simply resets the rotation values.

I have recorded a video [here](https://youtu.be/CfzjYxQHhMc).

Can anybody tell me how to do this correctly?
I would like to keep the "Group001" object because it gives me the possibility to rotate all of the objects, and I don't have to do this individually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem the hardcore way:

I delete the "Group001" object and created a new "Empty" object and parented the objects to it.

This "Empty" object had no weirdness and worked fine.